# Is it possible to detect android back button on web app?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, browser

I'm doing a PWA using Vue.js, i know that cordova can handle the android/iOS back button (the device back button, not the browser one), so it's ok.

How can i detect this on vuejs?

Comment: I think android's back button corresponds to the back-button of the browser's history. If your web-app keeps track of history, you should be able to use it.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: If so, i would like to treat 'back' for each location user is

Comment: I think it depends on the browser - in chrome the back button goes back in browser historty.

Comment: @eeerrrttt what would you like to achieve? In Android you have `onBackPressed()` method in your `Activity` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device back button is native feature of Android/ios, so can not detect event on click.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22479328)

Comment: @PhilippKief I'm fairly sure he does answer what was asked. He states that it can't be detected on press. I could be mistaken based on your upvote; if so can you inform me what I'm missing.